# Can you pull an enemy from an adjacent square to another adjacent square?

Tags: dnd-4e, forced-movement

Some background.

I Recently leveled up my Weaponmaster to L7. I took the power "Come and Get It." It allows me to *pull* anything in a burst 3 up to 2 squares and then try to hit them with my giant sword. However, it stipulates that they have to end adjacent to me.

So here is my question:

Can I pull an enemy who is already adjacent to me into another square that is adjacent to me? The other night I was dragging a whole slew of critters towards me and trying to figure out how to get them all adjacent to me. I already had one in the top right corner, and there was one above that one. I was wondering if I could slide the one in the top right corner into the square immediately to my right and slide the other one into the space it left.

Could I have done this? I know they have to end up closer to me as its a pull, but can it go adjacent to adjacent?

Comment: I would shift away 1 square (to prevent an OA) and then do your ability.

Comment: @Total - it was about attempting optimal positioning to suck in the most critters (there were about 10 or so in an area). I think I managed to get about 6 of them around me. It was kind of epic, especially when I activated Rain of Steel...:). I didn't have an action point, but my favorite L7 fighter nova is Come and get it + Sweeping Blow + Rain of Steel. Its a bit of waste of mass marking powers, but the DM's face when you take out 6 or 7 little guys is worth it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No. Each square of a pull most move them closer to you (just as each square of a push must move them further away). Holding distance is reserved for slides.

> Pull: "Each square you move it must bring it nearer to you."

PHB: page 285

Comment: Do you have a page reference or link for this rule?

Comment: Pull: "Each square you move it must bring it nearer to you." (PHB: page 285); Push: "each square you move it must place it farther away from you" (PHB: page 285); Slide: "no restriction on the direction you can move it" (PHB: page 285).

Comment: I assume that based on most other rulings in 4e, no special significance is given to corner squares vs side squares. Is this correct?

Comment: Correct - 4E makes no distinction between corner and side adjacency

Comment: I seem to vaguely remember a graphic which showed valid charges.  That would be useful also for pulls and pushes.

Comment: @gomad Yep. (Thanks to Ace and Ross for the assist).

Comment: @Allen Gould - Saw that, and +1ed shortly thereafter!