# What constitutes "closer" on a map of squares?

Tags: dnd-4e, forced-movement

[This answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/8742/can-you-pull-an-enemy-from-an-adjacent-square-to-another-adjacent-square/8743#8743) makes it clear that each pull must result in the enemy moving closer to the puller. But on a square grid, don't you count each edge that must be crossed as a unit of distance? For example:

```
-------
|T|*|X|         P = Puller         X = Illegal New Position
-------
|*|P|X|         T = Target 
-------
|X|X|X|         * = Legal New Position
-------
```

If the Puller pulls the Target, are the new positions (*) legal?

It seems to me that the distance from T to P is 2 but the distance from * to P is 1. And therefore it seems to me that Puller couldn't pull T to any of the X squares because the number of edges goes from 1 to 2 as you move from a * square to an X square.

Is this the correct interpretation of the movement rules in 4e?

Comment: I think the real crux here is once something is adjacent to you can you make it "more adjacent"?

Comment: I think the more interesting case is one square further out from this. If T is in the top left corner one square farther out (or even 2 squares farther out, can he be pulled into an adjacent square, and which adjacent squares can he be pulled into.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In D&D 4e, diagonal movement is equivalent to horizontal/vertical movement. In your diagram, the target **cannot** be pulled closer without entering the square of the puller. He is already 1 square away, so anything closer would have to be 0 squares.

Comment: To phrase it in the language of the question: A diagonal move is not "across the edge down, then across the edge over" it is "across the (corner) edge."

Comment: @AceCalhoon - So: "Distance is each edge or vertex (corner) that must be crossed to reach a given square"? @dpatchery - Page reference and / or rules quotation? Thanks very much for clearing this up, guys, I don't know how I hadn't seen that yet...

Comment: @gomad It'll have to wait until I get home, then I'll throw in a reference.

Comment: @gomad Yes, vertex would be the correct word. Re: Page reference: "To determine the range between you and a target, count the number of squares between you, including at least one square that the target occupies." (PHB: page 273)

Comment: @gomad "When counting the distance from one square to another, start counting from any adjacent square (even one that is diagonally adjacent but around the corner) and then count around solid obstacles that fill their squares. You must choose the most direct path to a target when counting squares for range." (PHB: page 273)

Comment: Reiterating this answer: "Closer" means decreasing the range by at least 1 square. Note that some targets can be moved to the same square (a range of 0.)